# Multi-part ST_GEOMETRY: Does the feature-part array start at 1 or 0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, oracle-dbms, multipart, st-geometry

*Oracle 18c; ArcGIS 10.7.1*

I have an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polyline FC that has multi-part features.

[image]

---

Question:

What method does ArcGIS use to assign numbers to the feature-parts in the array?

- Do the part numbers start at 1 or 0?

Comment: This is less a GIS issue than an IT one. Most programming languages evolved from 'C' (to include C++, C#, Java, and Python) use a zero-based index. SQL uses a one-based index.

Answer (score 0):

**ArcObjects:**

It looks like ArcObjects in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 starts the array at `0`.

[image]

---

**SDE.ST_GEOMETRY:**

Whereas SDE.ST_GEOMETRY appears to start the array at `1`.

```
select
    road_id,
    n.num as part,
    sde.st_geometryn(shape,n.num) as shape
from
    roads
cross join
    numbers n
where
    n.num <= sde.st_numgeometries(shape)
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

The numbering conventions mentioned also apply to numbering **vertices** too.

ArcObjects starts at `0`, SDE.ST_GEOMETRY starts at `1`.